# How do I delete a directory if a file has changed using Chef?

Tags: java, tomcat, chef-infra

I want to create a Chef recipe for deploying a java application using tomcat. When I update the java application(.WAR file in my cookbook, upload and get a node to run the updated cookbook), I want Chef to stop tomcat, delete the contents of tomcat/webapps folder, copy the new war and then start tomcat again.

I've seen syntax for if File.exists, but have not seen anything for if . How can I do this?
I presume Chef has this functionality, since it updates files only if their checksum changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing some details, for example how do you put WAR file in proper location. So I'll assume you use `cookbook_file` resource.

```
cookbook_file "path/to/release.war" do
  notifies :execute, "cleanup tomcat webapp directory", :before
  notifies :start,  "service[tomcat]"
end

execute "cleanup tomcat directory" do
  notifies :stop, "service[tomcat]", :before
  command "rm -r path/tomcat/webapps/*"
  action :nothing 
end
```

Service tomcat must be available in scope of resource where you'll be putting this code, before timer requires chef 12.7 afair.

However this solution may introduce downtime for time of running `rm -r` and requires full stop/start of tomcat. Wouldn't it be better to use [hot deploy](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-deploy-procedures) (on running server)?